# Displaying latex on a GUI with python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a "calculator" to integrate and derivate math equations.
And I would like to display the result in the gui in latex.

Does anyone know to create this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk




def integrate():
    import sympy as sp

    x=sp.Symbol('x')
    eq.get()
    integral=sp.integrate(eq,x)
    var.set('Integration result='+ 'C\u2081')

win=tk.Tk()   # defines window

win2=ttk.Labelframe(win,text='')
win2.grid(column=0, row=0)

# Creates a static txt label 
eq_static=ttk.Label(win2,text='Introduce the equation f(x)',font=("Times New Roman", 14))
eq_static.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=5,pady=5)

eq=tk.StringVar()
eq_Entered=ttk.Entry(win2,width=40, textvariable=eq)
eq_Entered.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=5,pady=5)
# Creates a static txt label 
var=tk.StringVar()
eq_static=ttk.Label(win2,textvariable=var,font=("Times New Roman", 14))
var.set('Result')
eq_static.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=5,pady=5)
# Calculate button

action=ttk.Button(win2,text='Integrate',command=integrate)
action.grid(column=2,row=0,padx=5,pady=5)
win2.mainloop()
```

Comment: sympy has a [`preview` function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.preview.preview) that does this.

Comment: Is it able to print in a position on a GUI?

Comment: It just makes an image. You can do anything you want with the resulting image, including displaying it in a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [sympy.preview](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.preview.preview) function to generate an image, and then use BytesIO and PIL to make it compatible with tkinter. Here's a guess:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sympy as sp
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def integrate():
    x=sp.Symbol('x')
    integral=sp.integrate(eq.get(),x)
    var.set('Integration result='+ 'C\u2081')
    obj = BytesIO()
    sp.preview(integral, viewer='BytesIO', output='png', outputbuffer=obj)
    obj.seek(0)
    img_lbl.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(obj))
    img_lbl.config(image=img_lbl.img)

win=tk.Tk()   # defines window

win2=ttk.Labelframe(win,text='')
win2.grid(column=0, row=0)

# Creates a static txt label
eq_static=ttk.Label(win2,text='Introduce the equation f(x)',font=("Times New Roman", 14))
eq_static.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=5,pady=5)

eq=tk.StringVar(value='4*x')
eq_Entered=ttk.Entry(win2,width=40, textvariable=eq)
eq_Entered.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=5,pady=5)
# Creates a static txt label
var=tk.StringVar()
eq_static=ttk.Label(win2,textvariable=var,font=("Times New Roman", 14))
var.set('Result')
eq_static.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=5,pady=5)
# Calculate button

img_lbl = tk.Label(win2)
img_lbl.grid()

action=ttk.Button(win2,text='Integrate',command=integrate)
action.grid(column=2,row=0,padx=5,pady=5)
win2.mainloop()
```

Also note I fixed your integrate call to pass the *content* of the StringVar, not the StringVar itself, to sympy.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for kind help!
However, I am getting an error

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
...

Comment: there's no way for me to help if you don't show me the entire error.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\User \anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/pv/Documents/Python Scripts/scripts/Integrate_derivate_ODE.py", line 35, in integrate
    sp.preview(integral, viewer='BytesIO', output='png', outputbuffer=obj)
  File "C:\\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\preview.py", line 196, in preview
    raise RuntimeError("latex program is not installed")
RuntimeError: latex program is not installed
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Well that error is pretty self explanatory. You don't have a latex program installed, so sympy can't use it to make images. Install a latex program. [This will probably work for you](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe).

Comment: After installation I am getting this: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ' File "C:\Users\pv\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/pv/Documents/Python Scripts/scripts/Integrate_derivate_ODE.py", line 34, in integrate
    obj = BytesIO()
NameError: name 'BytesIO' is not defined'

Comment: That error means you didn't add the `from io import BytesIO` on the top. Don't forget the PIL import as well